# Pandoc for generating html file not using RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, pandoc

I'd like to generate html file via script below which is a part of complex source code but I don't want to install RStudio on users machine.

I'm using pandoc available at: [pandoc from github](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/1.16.0.2) and the reference for path to this pandoc file is used in Sys.setenv: "C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Pandoc".

If I use RSTUDIO_PANDOC in Sys.setenv command, everything works fine in my script below but I'm just confused if RSTUDIO_PANDOC in Sys.setenv command uses default RStudio pandoc file which I don't wanna use. Is there any replacement by RSTUDIO_PANDOC to be sure I don't need RStudio to be installed on user's machine and I can refer only to pandoc file what I downloaded from the link above.

```
Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Pandoc")
setwd("C:/Users/username/interactiveKnitr") # set path to .Rmd file
knit('knit.Rmd') # creates md file
render('knit.Rmd') # creates html file
```

Thank you very much for any of your explanation and help on this. I'm very new in this area.

Comment: Have you tried `knitr::pandoc`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. That generates html but without plot_ly stuffs and in incorrect format. That's the reason why I'm using knit and render to .Rmd file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the package `pander` form within R. Despite of that I usually prefer to install `pandoc` myself and to use a system call if I need to run everything form R.

```
knit (input = "file.Rmd", output = "file.md")
system ("pandoc file.md")
```

Then is easier to tune `pandoc` parameters and you make sure to run the version you have installed. It makes also things easier if you want to create *tex* or *pdf* version of the document.

Comment: And do you still need to use Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Pandoc")?

Comment: I do not think so. Indeed I use it outside Rstudio (also form R studio). The call to `knitr` depends just on `knitr` parameters and the call to system should not be affected by Rstudio parameters... but I guess you can make sure of the pandoc version you are using setting the full path in your system call `system ("C:/User..../pandoc file.md")`

Comment: I have no idea how can I test this, because I don't want to uninstall RStudio from my pc :-)

Comment: Run R outside Rstudio. If you are in Windows you can use the standard R interface or use the batch mode form the DOS shell. See here http://www.statmethods.net/interface/batch.html. Writhe your file.Rmd with any editor (Rstudio for instance) save it just as it is (a text file) and then close Rstudio and open R without it. Remember to load the knitr package.