# Converting Rmarkdown to PDF without RStudio

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I would like to convert a `*.Rmd` to document to PDF ***without*** [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) being available.

## Current approach

Current approach follows the following steps:

1. `*.Rmd` document is passed to `knitr`: **`knit(input = "report.Rmd"))`**
2. Obtained md is converted via pandoc:

   ```
   # Convert
   pandoc --smart --to latex \
          --latex-engine pdflatex \
          -s report.md \
          -o report.PDF
   ```

### Problems

This results in the following problems, the top section of the *Rmarkdown* document:

```
---
title:  "Report Title"
author: "Person"
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
---
```

and shows as:

[image: top document section]

all text is centered, whereas I would like for it to be left-aligned:

[image: no-left aligned]

## Possible approach

I would like to make use of the [**`rmarkdown::render`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/rmarkdown.pdf); however, despite setting `RSTUDIO_PANDOC` (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936806/1655567)), the command fails on `pandoc` not being available.

## Desired outcome

I don't care much whether the utilised mechanism makes use of the `rmarkdown::render`, what I want to achieve is:

- Landscape page layout across all pages
- Left-aligned text
- Ability to exercise minimum control over the document by controlling default fonts

---

- *Ideally, I would like to do as much as in the `*.Rmd` file as possible without the need to add parameters to the `pandoc` command.*

## Updates, following comments

- I'm working on Linux and pandoc is installed, I can execute `pandoc` command pass files and generate exports with no problems. It only doesn't work with the `rmarkdown::render` package.
- Concerning the hooks and `*.Rmd` files, this is what I'm trying to understand as I see that that the first section of my `*.Rmd` file is ignored. The current process looks as follows:

  - **`*.Rmd`** (not much in it, just title section and dummy text and code that renders but wrongly justified) **>**
  - **`*.R`** file running one line `knit(input = "report.Rmd"))` **>**
  - **`*.sh`** file running `pandoc` command and generating PDF

### Concerning:

> if all that is in place, it is indeed just a call to
>   `rmarkdown::render(...)`

The `rmarkdown::render(...)` fails:
`Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 is required and was not found ...`
However:

```
>> rmarkdown::pandoc_available()
[1] TRUE
```

and:

```
$ pandoc -v
pandoc 1.9.4.1 (...)
```

The `RSTUDIO_PANDOC` points to pandoc.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- *"the command fails on pandoc not being available."* well you *must*  have `pandoc` installed in order to call it -- but you didn't say what OS you have.  On Linux it is pretty trivial to install `pandoc` from the package manager; otherwise jgm has binaries for you on the site; "should" be similar on OS X
- for different styling you need to modify the LaTeX code which you can via numerous hooks to include macro files; see the RMarkdown cheat sheets for detail
- if you want to exercise more control, you can supply your own template; I have done so in the [tint package](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/tint)
  (which is also on CRAN)
- if all that is in place, it is indeed just a call to `rmarkdown::render(...)`

Answer (score 0):

> Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 is required and was not found

I think the error says it plainly: you need pandoc 1.12.3 and you have pandoc 1.9.4.1

I do not know, however, why such a specific version is required.